# Team Services releasing wrong project in multi-project solution

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been setting up Continuous integration, and deployment in Team Foundation Server Online. When VSTSreleases the build to the DEV server (with the IIS Deployment template) the wrong project is being released.

The image below shows the project structure in my solution (asp.net core). I just need to deploy the WebApp.Web.MVC project which has dependencies on several other projects in the solution. Instead, VSTS deploys the WebApp.Application.Shared project.

[image: Solution/folder structure]

I've tried moving the MVC project to the top of the list by putting an A in front of it. Also tried adding a parameter in the VSTS build definition with name 'Project' and value 'WebApp.Web.Mvc'. No results though.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the buildstep in which you're telling VSTS to release your project?

Comment: Do you mean the release definition that picks up the builds? Got a screenshot here: [link](https://imgur.com/a/0Io04)

Comment: Not the workflow, the task that does the actual work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to solve this problem by doing the following:

I added an additional step in the build process, first the entire solution is build, and then the second step is to build only the MVC project by referring to the mvc.csproj. Now, only the MVC project and its dependencies are being released to the IIS website.

[Entire solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLynz.png)

[Only MVC project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOwPg.png)